# Permissions for simple text-replace Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension I've developed for Chrome (and Firefox, down the road), but can't get it to work when downloaded from the App Store. I think the problem is the permissions.

It's simple: the extension looks for particular text on a page (say: "dog") and highlights it. Just a simple HTML swap.

The .crx file includes the manifest and the javascript which does the replacement (and works locally). This is packaged with the icon and another version of the manifest (unless I'm doing something wrong here?) and submitted to the store. I tried various permissions (like "activetab") but it didn't work.

The three files are:

**manifest.json** (sits outside .crx)

```
{
    "name": "[name]",
    "version": "[version]",
    "description": "[description]",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
        },
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "content_scripts":
        [
            {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": ["script.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
            }
        ]
}
```

**manifest.json** (sits inside the .crx)

```
{
    "name": "[name]",
    "version": "[version]",
    "description": "[description]",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "author": "[author]",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "content_scripts":
        [
            {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": ["script.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
            }
        ]
}
```

**script.js** (sits inside the .crx)
Runs the actual search and replace. Runs without issue locally.

What am I doing wrong? Pulling out my hair.

Comment: One addition: I stripped out the permissions tag I at one point had. So no permissions are currently set.

Comment: The info in the question is insufficient to diagnose the problem. Try to make a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: OK. Fleshed this out. Thanks.

Comment: `permissions` isn't necessary here as it does nothing at all for content_scripts. I still don't see MCVE here which is a set of info that allows reproducing the problem.